# Xcode crashes with cocos2d 2.1 when try to build

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, osx-mountain-lion

After updating OSX and Xcode to latest versions (10.8.4 | 4.6.3) projects with cocos2d 2.0 works fine but...
When I tryed update cocos2d to 2.1 new projects want not build. Xcode just closes with error.

Full error description here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JhqD3CW2JRKEXZquQIYN4grVG3siDL4jqcFByhGDgGM

After this error projects with c2d 2.0 that works before starts crashes too.
Back cocos to v2.0 does not give any profit.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint that captures all exceptions.

Comment: It looks like Xcode was attempting to handle a key event; were you trying to cancel the build or something?

Comment: In Xcode go to "the breakpoint navigator". Click on the plus-sign down in the bottom and choose "Add Exception Breakpoint"

Comment: @Mikael That won't affect Xcode itself crashing.

Comment: No it won't, but it will probably show you where in the code the crash occured.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved.

I use RealVNC server on my home mac and client on win7 PC at work.
Xcode crashes when I try build/run using shortcuts (command+R, command+B, sometimes command+z)
When I do this using menu, it works fine.
Weird, why this starts after cocos2d 2.1 installed...

So, I think, problem with OSX 10.8.4 + RealVNC.
Weird weird weird...

Directly Mac works fine.

P.S. I hope this will be helpful for another internet pilgrims.